# Squaring sides of an inequality

Tags: inequality

I want to know what will happen to the inequality in these cases

$a>x>b$
If $a$ and $b$ negative 
When i square the both sides of it 
Is it going to be 
$b^2>x^2>a^2$

Ok but what would happen if  $a$ is a positive and $b$ is a negative number when i square ? EXAMPLE
$2>x>-1$  another case 
$2>x>-4$

i forgot  mentioning this case ? 
If it is something like

$2>x>-2$

Comment: you need to consider absolute values here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that all values in mentioned inequalities are real numbers.

When you square something the sign goes out: $x^2 = (-x)^2 = \vert x \vert^2$. So the form of your inequality after applying the power of two depends on absolute values. Suppose you had $a<x<b$ such that $\vert a \vert < \vert b \vert$, then nothing changes, you still has $a^2 < x^2 < b^2$. This is a safe condition for squaring your inequality. Another possible case is when the condition $\vert a \vert < \vert b \vert$ is not satisfied, for example, consider the following inequality: $-2 < x < 1$. After straightforward squaring it becomes $4 < x^2 < 1$, which is obviously incorrect, but you can now rewrite it as $1 < x^2 < 4$ or $b^2 < x^2 < a^2$.

So the general rule is that for given inequality $a < x < b$ if $\vert a \vert < \vert b \vert$ then $a^2 < x^2 < b^2$, else if $\vert a \vert > \vert b \vert$ then $b^2 < x^2 < a^2$.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful

Comment: There is a case  i didnt mention in my question          which like this EXAMPLE            1>x>-1

Answer (score 1):

You can consider it like this one in general: Suppose we have $a>0$, $b<0$ and $a>x>b$. Then, we can seperate this inequality as 
$$a>x \ge 0 \lor 0 >x>b$$ 
Then if we square the terms in inequalities, our expression becomes 
$$a^2>x^2 \ge 0 \lor b^2>x^2>0$$
Since we have a logical or, solution set for $x^2$ is the union of the solution sets of these seperate inequalities, that is, if $a^2\ge b^2$ then we have $a^2>x^2 \ge 0$ and otherwise, we have $b^2 >x^2 \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if the square is greater, you have to compare the absolute values of a and b, meaning $|a|$ and $|b|$.  For instance $|2| = 2$, $|-4| = 4$.

If $a = 2$ and $b = -2$, to find if $a^2$ or $b^2$ is greater. you compare $|a|$ and $|b|$.  Here, $|a| = 2$ and $|b| = 2$.  Since $|a|=|b|$, $a^2=b^2$.  This is how you determine the resultant inequality.  In this case then, there will be no solutions to x.

Comment: What should be done with this 
$2>x>-2$

Comment: ok @MohammedAmayreh edited already

Comment: my question is what will be the values of x after squaring the inequality

Comment: But if we take numbers between  - 2 and 2  and square them the values of x^2  will be greater or equal to 0 and less than 4, so can we say that the   square of 
$2>x>-2$    is 
$4>x^2>0$ ?